# check input on length and use bootstrap validation

Tags: javascript, validation, bootstrap-4

I have - I think so - a very simple question. I'm working with `Bootstrap 4.6` and I want to have a `form-validation` for my `input`.

I need to check if my `input` has a length of 5 or lower than the `validation` should be "not fullfiled" (red) otherwise if it's equal or higher than 5 it should be fullfiled, so it should be green.

*red:*
[image]

*green:*
[image]

I want to have that `validation` from Bootstrap 4.6 - here is the link to this component: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/forms/#validation

Thanks in advance for helping me out!

Here you can see my code:

```
<form class="was-validated">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="validationTextarea">Textarea</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="validationTextarea" placeholder="Required example textarea" onkeyup="checkInput()" required></input>
  </div>
</form>
```

```
function checkInput() {
  var input = document.getElementById("validationTextarea").value;

  if(input.length < 5) {
    //it should be red
  } else if (input.length >= 5) {
    //it should be green
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not so clear what exactly do you want. Please be clear as much as you can. *I need to check if my input has a length of 5 or lower than the validation should be "not fullfiled" (red) otherwise if it's equal or higher than 5 it should be fullfiled, so it should be green.* and *I want to have that validation from Bootstrap 4.6 and don't want to color my letters red..*

Comment: Hi, updated it. Hopefully it's clear now after adding some pictures how it looks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want custom validation then you can

**1)** Remove the `was-validated` class from the `form` element, because you want to add custom validation

```
  <form class="m-3"> 
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="validationTextarea">Textarea</label>
      <input class="form-control is-invalid" id="validationTextarea" placeholder="Required example textarea" onkeyup="checkInput()" required></input>
    </div>
  </form>
```

**2)** Now comes the logic part, where you have to add `is-invalid` class if `values.length < 5` else add `is-valid` class.

const input = document.querySelector( "#validationTextarea" );

```
function checkInput() {
    var value = document.getElementById( "validationTextarea" ).value;

    if ( value.length < 5 ) {
        input.classList.remove( "is-valid" );
        input.classList.add( "is-invalid" );
    } else {
        input.classList.add( "is-valid" );
        input.classList.remove( "is-invalid" );
    }
}
```

```js
const input = document.querySelector("#validationTextarea");

function checkInput() {
  var value = document.getElementById("validationTextarea").value;

  if (value.length < 5) {
    input.classList.remove("is-valid");
    input.classList.add("is-invalid");
  } else {
    input.classList.add("is-valid");
    input.classList.remove("is-invalid");
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<form class="m-3">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="validationTextarea">Textarea</label>
    <input class="form-control is-invalid" id="validationTextarea" placeholder="Required example textarea" onkeyup="checkInput()" required></input>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: perfect solution - wasn't thinking about ```add``` or ```remove``` - thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

In React input.classList.remove/add didn't work for me. I used event.target.

```
function checkInput(event) {
const value = document.getElementById("validationTextarea").value;

if (value.length < 10 || value.length > 140) {
    event.target.classList.add("is-invalid");
} else {
    event.target.classList.remove("is-invalid");
    event.target.classList.add("is-valid");
}
```

}